# Convert Meteor Template to NodeJS/AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, templates, meteor

I have a current website made with Meteor that is based on Templates like:

```
<body>
  {{>section1}}
  {{>section2}}
  {{>section3}}
</body>

<template name="section1">
  <h1>This is Section 1</h1>
</template>

<template name="section2">
  <h1>This is Section 2</h1>
</template>

<template name="section3">
  <h1>This is Section 3</h1>
</template>
```

I would like to use now NodeJS/AngularJS. Does there is a simple way to manage HTML Templates with?

Comment: I think you can use handlebars

Comment: You would like to use NodeJS as a templating enginge? NodeJS is a server side platform

Comment: Hi Adam. Since Meteor is a Server + Client Framework I asked a way to implement template with another couple like NodeJS + AngularJS. Hi Codesingh, I will take a look on handlebars.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach this:

1) Stay with Meteor/Blaze - maybe not your preference, but it's quite easy to pick up, and while it's not fashionable, will work well, your downtime due to development will be minimal, and this will be the cheapest path.

2) You can use AngularJS with Meteor, which means you can re-use some of your Meteor code (but not much of it). Have a look at Urigo's excellent tutorials at https://angular-meteor.com/.

3) If you don't like the Blaze templating engine, you can move to React, which integrates well with Meteor - see the tutorial https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app - Again you can re-use a little of the existing code

4) If you are starting from scratch, you can use something like ExpressJS http://expressjs.com/ but that's just a starting point, you will need to write a whole bunch of code to replicate what Meteor does for you.

This is where responses will get quite opinionated - there are many ways to skin this cat, and everyone will recommend something they use and like. The fact that you ask this question suggests that you don't already know which way you would like to go.

As far as I know there are no tools for porting away from Meteor, and in any case the way it works is kind of unique, so any automated convertor is only going to do a percentage of the work, and leave you with a bit of puzzle to sort out.

All of the options (except staying with Meteor) will mean an almost total rewrite of the app. If you are prepared to do that, you should choose a technology that you have some skills in already

Comment: Hi Mikkel, thanks for your feedback. I like a lot Meteor, I was able to create the website with all functionalities I wanted to implement. The main issue I have currently is that the website takes around 10s to provide finalized view without client cache. This is too long. I was looking for NodeJS + "Some FrontEnd JS" in order to conserve same JS language from server/client and implement only mandatory lightweight functionnalities in order to improve loading times. The HTML Template feature from Blaze is very attractive, that's why I'm looking for same feature with NodeJS + AngularJS.